# How to create a function to be used in an std::ostream or std::cout

Tags: c++, iostream

Is there a way to create a function which you can use between two `<<` operators in an ostream?

Let's assume the function's name is `usd`, and might look something like:

```
std::ostream& usd(std::ostream& os, int value) {
    os << "$" << value << " USD";
    return os;
}
```

Then I would like to use it like:

```
int a = 5;
std::cout << "You have: " << usd(a) << std::endl;
```

Which would print:

> You have: $5 USD

I would prefer a solution without the need for a class. 
If you must use a class I would prefer not to mention the class at all when using the `usd` function. (For example how the `std::setw` function works)

**EDIT**:
In my implementation I intend to use the `std::hex` function, the one described above was just a simplified example but probably shouldn't have.

```
std::ostream& hex(std::ostream& os, int value) {
    os << "Hex: " << std::hex << value;
    return os;
}
```

So I am not sure if a function returning a simple string is sufficient.

Comment: Why don't you just create a function that returns simple std::string? Is there any use case where you really need the one you described?

Comment: @Bartłomiej, Didn't realize you could. I've been learning about overloading the `operator<<` for classes lately so thought the solution here might be in that direction.

Comment: @Bartłomiej, actually please see the edits I've made. Not sure how to implement a function that returns an std::string with my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do this without a class. However, it is easy to do with a class.

```
struct usd {
    int value;
    constexpr usd(int val) noexcept : value(val) {}
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, usd value) {
    os << "$" << value.value << " USD";
    return os;
}
```

for hex

```
struct hex {
    int value;
    constexpr hex(int val) noexcept : value(val) {}
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, hex value) {
    os << "Hex: " << std::hex << value.value;
    return os;
}
```

usage

```
int a = 5;
std::cout << "You have: " << usd(a) << std::endl;
std::cout << "You have: " << hex(a) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

To obtain the usage you described:

```
int a = 5;
std::cout << "You have: " << usd(a) << std::endl;
```

You'd simply need `usd(a)` to return something that you have an `ostream<<` operator for, like a `std::string`, and no custom `ostream<<` operator is needed.

For example:

```
std::string usd(int amount)
{
    return "$" + std::to_string(amount) + " USD";
}
```

You can write other functions to print in other currencies, or to convert between them, etc but if all you want to handle is USD, this would be sufficient.

---

If you used a class representing money, you could write an `ostream<<` for that class and you wouldn't need to call a function at all (given that your default `ostream<<` prints USD)

```
class Money
{
    int amount;
};

std::ostream& usd(std::ostream& os, Money value) {
    os << "$" << value.amount << " USD";
    return os;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Money a{5};
    std::cout << "You have: " << a << std::endl; // Prints "You have: $5 USD"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response. Please see my edit.